# Breaking out of a JavaScript for statement from within an if statement

Tags: javascript

This is what I want to do: cycle through a complex data structure and if one of the elements meets some condition, return it.  But I don't think it's possible to return from within an 'if' that's within my for loop.  What's the best practice?  Thanks.

```
function findIt(x) {
    for (i in someDataArray) {
        v = someDataArray[i];
        if (*v meets some condition*) {
            return v;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should probably try it first and then if it doesn't work come back and ask your question.  You can return from within a loop and/or if.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's perfectly legal to issue `return` statement from within an `if`.

The only issue here is what happens if it's not found?  Here the function will implicitly return `undefined`.  It may be better to make this explicit.  This is a matter of style though.

```
function findIt(x) {
    for (i in someDataArray) {
        v = someDataArray[i];
        if (*v meets some condition*) {
            return v;
        }
    }
    return undefined;
}
```

Comment: thanks!  yes, i didn't address all the outcomes, just to keep the question simple, but you answered the core question.

Answer (score 0):

you can return from anywhere you want.. with respect to best practice make sure that all your code paths return something and all the paths should return the same type of data.